# Error in retrieving the value of the output parameter of the stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure defined as follows to check the existence of the duplicate Email:

```
 USE [SQL2008_850994_onebizness]
 GO
 /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[EmailExists]    Script Date: 04/07/2013 15:14:22 ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmailExists]
 @EmailID Nvarchar(50),
 @Success int output, 
 @msg varchar(50) output  

 AS
 BEGIN
 IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Membership WHERE EmailId = @emailID) 
     OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Allocation where ResourceEmail=@emailID)
 begin
 set @Success=6
 set @msg='Duplicate Email found. Please try again.'      
 --Insert the records in the database
 end
 END
```

---

I am retrieving the value of the success in a C# code as follows:

```
 int returnVal = int.Parse(myCOmmand.Parameters["@Success"].ToString());
```

I am getting the error message "Input values are not in the correct format".

Can someone please let me know what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the Parameters as below

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Success", SqlDbType.Int));
myCommand.Parameters["@Success"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Then retrieve as

```
int returnVal = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@Success"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below code before you write the `int returnVal`

```
myCOmmand.Parameters.Add("@Success", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And then:

```
int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(myCOmmand.Parameters["@Success"].Value);
```